# Report to multiple Google Analytics properties or accounts from single Android app

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, firebase-analytics

We are currently using Firebase Analytics in a simple way in our Android app.

We have a requirement to report certain data (from a specific campaign) so it can be filtered and presented to a business partner without giving access to the rest of the data - we only want them to browser reports related to their campaign.

We have found that it's impossible to achieve using Firebase Analytics alone, and thus we're considering creating 2 Google Analytics properties and somehow reporting to them based on our runtime decisions inside the app.

However, that seems impossible as well, since Firebase allows linking to one specific Google Analytics property and offers zero flexibility in adding multiple properties or deciding which one to use programatically.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9289234?hl=en

Using multiple Firebase projects don't allow this flexibility as well, since analytics only get reported using the default one defined at build level.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#reliable-analytics

Any solutions, or should we move to another 3rd party analytics SDK just for this purpose?

Comment: Hey @SirKnigget, I'm facing the same issue. I want to create two different properties on the same Firebase project (one GA4 property and one GA-Universal). Have you solved your issue?